# ffmpeg spawned inside NodeJS doesn't output to a url

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, ffmpeg

I'm trying to run ffmpeg on Google Cloud (cloud functions) and I'm trying to have it output the files to a URL (of a Google Storage).

I'm spawning ffmpeg in NodeJS like so:

```javascript
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

spawn('ffmpeg', [
        '-i', 'input.mp4',
        // ... other arguments
        '-f', 'mp4',
        '-movflags', 'frag_keyframe+empty_moov' // needed for a URL output
        '-headers', `'Authorization: Bearer ${token}'`
        'https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/...'])
```

The problem is the file never gets uploaded, even though ffmpeg runs and exits with code 0.

The weird part is that if I run the exact same command directly from the terminal, it uploads the file.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -headers 'Authorization: Bearer XXX' 'https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/...'
```

This, I think, eliminates the possibility of any authentication issues or anything on the server-side.

I don't see any difference in the in the output (stderr).

Any idea why the Node-version doesn't upload the output and doesn't report any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix that worked (though, unclear to me exactly why it's requried) was to spawn the process inside a shell with:

```javascript
spawn('ffmpeg', [
        '-i', 'input.mp4',
        // ... other arguments
      ], 
      { shell: true })
```